# Удалить элемент в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```html
<div>
<li class="obj_1"></li>
<li class="obj_1"></li>//Надо чтобы удалялся именно этот
<li class="obJ_1"></li>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы элемент удалял сам себя? если точнее то как соединить remove и this чтобы удалялся именно этот элемент, по поводу removeChild знаю но это не то что нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

```html
<div>
  <li class="obj_1">не этот</li>
  <li class="obj_1" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
    Надо чтобы удалялся именно этот</li>
  <li class="obJ_1">не этот</li>
</div>
```

```js
function removeThatItem() {
  var item = document.querySelector("div li.obj_1:nth-child(2)");
  item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li class="obj_1">не этот</li>
  <li class="obj_1">
    Надо чтобы удалялся именно этот</li>
  <li class="obJ_1">не этот</li>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="removeThatItem()">Remove Item</button>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, а можно как-то на кнопку привязать чтобы при нажатии на нее срабатывало удаление?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин удаление чего?

Comment: Удаление этого элемента

Comment: [Node.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать, чтобы элемент удалял сам себя?

Проходим по всем елементам и вешаем событие, только элемент с определённым критерием будет удален, в этом примере это класс `delete`.

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
// Event on all li elements
li.forEach(function (e) { 
  e.addEventListener('click', function (ee) { 
     // Only class element with class delete
     if(ee.target.classList.contains('delete')){
        console.log(ee.target.textContent);
        // Node will be deleted
        ee.target.remove(e);
     }
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text 01</li>
  <li>Some text 02</li>
  <li class="delete">Some text 03</li>
  <li>Some text 04</li>
  <li>Some text 05</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Всё таки `classList.contains('delete')`

Comment: @vp_arth благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно сработает так - Добавить в элемент любое нужное событие для удаления:

```
onclick="removeDiv(this.id)";
```

И добавить в скриптах функцию:

```
function removeDiv(IdDiv){ document.getElementById(IdDiv).remove(); }
```

Это у меня див сам себя так удаляет.